# Why is my Promise based code pending and not resolving?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, express, promise

**CODE EDITED WITH SOURCE AND TUTORIAL REFERENCE**

I am working on this **Node.js REST API with RBAC, JWT, Repository and MVC pattern.** It seems the author is no longer active with the post. There are [part 1](https://medium.com/@michael.svr/node-js-rest-api-with-rbac-jwt-repository-and-mvc-pattern-part-1-f5717c0b7103), [part 2](https://medium.com/@michael.svr/node-js-rest-api-with-rbac-jwt-repository-and-mvc-pattern-part-2-a494a4b89d7) and [part 3](https://medium.com/@michael.svr/node-js-rest-api-with-rbac-jwt-repository-and-mvc-pattern-part-3-648c7b5a4700). Part 1 and 2 works fine. But when I get to part three, I am having issue with two of the  files.

**ISSUE 1: THE JAVASCRIPT UNSHIFT METHOD**

When I added the unshift method in line 26 to 29 of the appBase.js file in part 3, the code refuse to resolve on loading when I tested it on postman. But when I remove it, it works fine. In part 1 and 2, it was not included.  From the code, the method `_createRouteBoundAction` now applies authenticate and authorize middlewares to each application route. This means that user has to have correct JWT token to access these routes. According to the author, the unshift method was meant to Authenticate and Authorize user by token. Why is the unshift not working? Is it because of the two parameters passed into it i.e. `this.security.authenticate(), this.security.authorise(controllerClass.name, method)`

```
_createRouteBoundAction(controllerClass, httpMethod) {
    const result = [
      (req, res) => {
        this._buildControllerInstance(controllerClass, req, res)[httpMethod]();
      }];

      result.unshift( 
        this.security.authenticate(),
        this.security.authorise(controllerClass.name, httpMethod),
    );

    return result;
  }
```

**ISSUE 2: getURI FUNCTION FAIL TO RESOLVE**

When I make the suggested changes in part 3, the getURI function fail to resolve in the URIGenerator.js file inside the routing folder. That is, when I tested it in Postman, the test keep loading and fail to resolve.

```
const queryString = require('query-string');
const RoutesCollection = require('./routesCollection');

class URIGenerator {
  constructor(security, role) {
    this.security = security;
    this.role = role;
  }

  getURI(controllerAction, params, id) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const caArray = controllerAction.split('_');
      const routeData = RoutesCollection[caArray[0]][caArray[1]];
      this.security.hasAccess(this.role, routeData.controller, routeData.action, (err, can) => {
        if (can) {
          const uri = params ? this._bindParams(routeData.uri, params) : routeData.uri;
          resolve({ id: id || routeData.action, method: routeData.method, uri });
        } else {
          resolve(null);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  _bindParams(uri, params) {
    let match;
    let replacement;
    const replacedParams = [];

    while (match = /:([\w_]+)\??/ig.exec(uri)) {
      replacement = params[match[1]].toString() || '';
      if (replacement === '') {
        uri = uri.replace(`/${match[0]}`);
      } else {
        uri = uri.replace(match[0], replacement);
        replacedParams.push(match[1]);
      }
    }

    const paramsForQueryString = {};
    Object.keys(params).forEach((p) => {
      if (!replacedParams.includes(p)) {
        paramsForQueryString[p] = params[p];
      }
    });

    if (Object.keys(paramsForQueryString).length > 0) {
      uri = `${uri}?${queryString.stringify(paramsForQueryString)}`;
    }

    return uri;
  }
}

module.exports = URIGenerator;
```

Meanwhile, when I use the getURI function as it was in part 1 it works. So, I am thinking it's because the getURI function fail to resolve.

Comment: Could you show the code where `getURI` method is used/invoked ?

Comment: `it calls the _bindParams function` - it resolves after that, what makes you think it's pending?

Comment: 1) How does Postman bring any conclusive proof of a promise resolving…? 2) If `_bindParam` throws an error, the promise might not resolve.

Comment: Shouldn't your `Promise` `reject()` when `can` is false?

Comment: @JaromandaX and @deceze when I remove the Promise from the getURI function it works.                                                                                                   
 ``` 
  getURI(controllerAction, params, id) {
    const caArray = controllerAction.split('_');
    const routeData = RoutesCollection[caArray[0]][caArray[1]];
    const uri = params ? this._bindParams(routeData.uri, params) : routeData.uri;

    return {
      id: id || routeData.action,
      method: routeData.httpMethod,
      uri,
    };
  }
```

Comment: @Titulum yes it will reject.

Comment: 1) What is calling `getURI`? Is *it* awaiting the promise? 2) Again, how does Postman factor into this as conclusive test tool?

Comment: what makes you think the promise is pending and the code that you posted *doesn't work* ... what *doesn't work*

Comment: @deceze if the promise resolve, the URIGenerator will generate the URI and it will display in Postman.

Comment: what will display where in postman?

Comment: @Jaromanda this file is a URIGenerator. When you try to access a route. It will check your role to see if you have the permission to access the resource. If you can, it will go ahead to display the request. I'm using postman.

Comment: Postman isn't helpful here, since Postman doesn't call the promise. The chain is Postman → HTTP request → ???? → `getURI` → promise → ???? → HTTP → Postman. It's entirely unclear whether the problem is in `getURI` or in "????".

Comment: As Boney asked, can you show from where `getURI()` is getting called? Like from `Controller`?

Comment: A `new Promise()` will automatically reject in response to a synchronous throw in its constructor. 
Nodeback code is not synchronous. If something in a nodeback throws, the Promise will not be automatically rejected.
If a nodeback error is exposed (first nodeback arg), again the Promise will not be automatically rejected.
So, if `_bindParams()` was to throw because eg the expression `queryString.stringify(paramsForQueryString)` threw, then the Promise returned by `getURI()` would hang.

Comment: @Bonny getURI method receives string which represents controller and its action in the following format ControllerName_actionName. The second parameter — route parameter which should be bound to URI. The third parameter — name of the URI it represents (default is controllers’ action name).